# warning: kibana Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I put the  ip address of  elasticsearch container in elasticsearch_url /
and I tried also to use  elasticsearch_url:http://localhost:9200 but I got the same warrning: knowing that :
I could access to the Dashboard of kibana
And when I did curl "http:/IP_addres_of_the_container_elk:9200

```
{
  "name" : "qgn5tIw",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "UxAne7DGT6-lF9yp7hadYw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

this is my docker-compose :

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    hostname: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - http.port=9200
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.4
    environment:
      - elasticsearch_url= http://172.18.0.2:9200
      - verify_ssl= false
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/kibana/config/data
    ports:
     - 5601:5601
    depends_on
     - elasticsearch
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
```

Could any one help please ? did I miss something ?

Comment: Dont use an IP when on docker, instead use your container_name like `elasticsearch_url= http://elasticsearch:9200` in your kibana config.

Comment: I did this but it still the same warning

Answer (score 0):

You have to add elasticsearch container as a link

```
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.2.4
    environment:
      - elasticsearch_url= http://172.18.0.2:9200
      - verify_ssl= false
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/kibana/config/data
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch
```

Comment: In the Docker documentation --- *[Links] are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name*

Answer (score 0):

Creating a docker network should solve the problem. It may give you the warning at the startup, but I believe it is normal. Wait a couple of seconds and it will connect.

Lastly, as others stated, do not hardcode the IP.

Try the following :

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - esnet
    depends_on:
        - elasticsearch     

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Comment: Thanks ,it works well,  I waited a couple of seconds and  it connect. but the network is creating in default by docker-compose